# GDB, break condition, check NULL pointer

Tags: c, gdb, conditional-breakpoint

I want to set a break point, and only stop at it, when one pointer called `rc` is `NULL`.

I did like that

```
      b task.c:190 if rc==NULL
```

but gdb says, `NULL` would be unrecognized, so I changed to

```
      b task.c:190 if(!rc)
```

which seems worked.

But I am not very sure, correct me if I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try to re-compile your project with CFLAG -ggdb3, then set the break point.Or use (void *)0 instead of `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

NULL is a C macro whose value is set to 0
Probably the gdb is not able to resolve the macro value.

Comment: `NULL` typically is `#define`d as `((void *) 0)`, that a "`NULL`-pointer".